# c# high CPU load on HTTP requests

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I have a bit of code that is responsible for doing http requests, there can be hundreds of threads per application that are active at a time.

Normally this works fine, however, when there are connection issues(at least I presume this to be the case) the code seems to use an excessive amount of CPU, upto 100%.

This is the piece of code in question:

```
 while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    while (threadNr > newViewerCount || threadNr >= (proxies.Count))
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    }

                    int sleepTimer = 4400 - (int)elapsed;
                    if (sleepTimer < 0)
                    {

                        sleepTimer = 1000;
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(sleepTimer);

                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(rc.url);

                    request.Method = "GET";
                    request.UserAgent = agent;
                    request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
                    request.Timeout = 5000;

                    request.CookieContainer = ck;
                    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
                    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                    request.UserAgent = userAgents[3];

                    HttpWebResponse webresponse;
                    using (webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                    {

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    int sl = 1500;
                    if (e.Message.Contains("timed"))
                    {
                        elapsed = 4399;
                        sl = 0;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(sl);
                    Console.WriteLine("Download exception:" + e.Message);

                    if (e.Message.Contains("404"))
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                        rc = getTokenUrl(proxy, ck); 
                    }

                    if (e.Message.Contains("forbidden"))
                    {
                        rc = getTokenUrl(proxy, ck);
                        Console.WriteLine("forbidden " + e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

This application is running 24/7, and most of the time it's okay. But at certain times it just starts using 100% cpu. I believe this happens when the proxies are taking long to respond. Why could this possibly be the case, is there something in the code that I am overlooking that could cause the application to use 100% cpu?

Comment: can you explain the reasoning behind the inner and outer while loops? particularly the outer While(true). I presume your multi threading is out-with the code sample you provided? I am seeing nothing that is multi-threaded about the code you posted.

Comment: Hello, I spawn hundreds of threads in another method that execute this code. The reasoning for the while loops is that I have execute a request to a specific url once every few seconds. The other while loop that you see ensures that I have all the needed data to complete the request.

Comment: not sure why it would run at 100% with all the thread.sleeps you have, but while(true) is probably the cause. if some condition occurs where an exception containing the word 'timed' is thrown, you could infinite loop with no sleep

Comment: I suggest you refactor to use a list of Tasks

Comment: Is there some way I could pinpoint what exactly is causing the load in the application? Keep in mind that the issue seems to be situational.

Answer (score 0):

You have a forever loop with `while (true)`, then there is an exception with message containing "timed", so s1 is set to zero and the loop is resumed. Elapsed is 4399, you try to sleep for 1 millisecond, which might be actually zero. So of course it is using all available CPU power possible since these conditions just keep on happening and there are no sleeps anywhere.

As was suggested, Tasks might be a better way to handle this and it's quite bad practice to have an eternal thread with no way of exiting or handling all error situations.

Also I wouldn't use e.Message as a way to determine what happened. What if the code is run on a machine that speaks French, for example?

Comment: It only happens when theres a timeout though, so that means that the thread was doing something else for 5+ seconds by defintion.

Comment: Yes, at first, and after that timeout it loops back and tries again and timeouts and does again and nowhere is there any sleeps in between. Eternal busy loop.

Comment: Even with a thread.sleep(8000) in the catch block it causes the cpu to run at 100%. I am utterly puzzled how this is technically even possible.